# fosuserbundle with hundreds of users

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

i want to use Fosuserbundle in my symfony2 project, i followed the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md)

all work fine and i created the first user by the command :

```
php app/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword
```

but the problem is that i have hundreds of users that i must create, should i create them by

this command, it is not logic right?? so how can i do? is there any other way than this

bundle to do authentication

Comment: You can use the UserManager class and its createUser() method
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md

Comment: THanks but is there any other way than using the Fosuserbundle because i find it is difficult to work with it

Comment: Of course you can instantiate and persist your user model as you usually do. Then call the $userManager->updateUser($user) if you want.